# Install Virtual PC on Windows 7 Professional installed on MacBook Pro

Tags: windows-7, mac, microsoft-virtual-pc, boot-camp

I'm trying to install Windows XP Virtual PC on Windows 7, on a MacBook Pro. Is it possible?
Windows 7 was installed using Boot Camp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. I just installed it and it's working without problems. I was having trouble installing it because I wasn't following every step.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, because really Windows 7 works just fine on any Mac (even w/o using boot camp), and Mac has the same CPU architecture as any PC (assuming you use an intel mac), you should be able to do anything in Windows 7 on a mac that you could do on a pc. Therefore, unless there is a strange incompatibility (most likely coming from Windows 7, not from Macintosh), you should definitely be able to run an XP VM on your Win7 partition.